# Calculating Hubble's Parameter $H$ at $x=\frac{Q}{T}=1$ for Neutron Abundance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology

In Dodelson's Modern Cosmology on p. 67 under Neutron Abundance section, he calculates

$$H(x=1) = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^3GQ^4}{45}}\sqrt{10.75} = 1.13\ \mathrm{s^{-1}}$$

where $x=\frac{Q}{T}$, and $T$ is temperature. Now with $Q= m_n-m_p=1.293\ \mathrm{MeV}$ and converting it to Joules, I am not able to get this value. Please give a hint as to how to re-produce this number.